# []' is not assignable to type 'InternalTransfert[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

In the `getInternalTransfert()` method, I would like to display the `svm` variable.

However, I got an error message for the next line:

```
this.internalTransfertLines = res.TITRE.map(
  ...
```

```
Type '{ svm: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'InternalTransfert[]'.
Type '{ svm: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'InternalTransfert': 
isin, stock, label, place, and 4 more.ts(2322)
```

[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slnnU.png)

TS

```
export class InternalTransfertWatchComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private unsubscribe$ = new Subject < void > ();
    internalTransfertLines: InternalTransfert[] = [];

    constructor(private service: InternalTransfertWatchService) {}


    ngOnInit(): void {}

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.unsubscribe$.next();
        this.unsubscribe$.complete();
    }


    getInternalTransfert(): void {
        this.service.getInternalTransfert().pipe(
            takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
        ).subscribe(res => {
            if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
                this.internalTransfertLines = res.TITRE.map(
                    internalTransfertLine => {
                        return {
                            svm: internalTransfertLine.SVM,
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    }

}
```

internal-transfert.response.ts

```
export interface InternalTransfertResponse extends ApiResponse {
    TITRE: {
        SVM: number;
        ISIN: string;
        STOCK: string;
        LABEL: string;
        PLACE: number;
        PLACELABEL: string;
        REGR: number;
        REGLABEL: string;
        DEVISE: string;
    } [];
}
```

internal-transfert.ts

```
export interface InternalTransfert {
    svm: number;
    isin: string;
    stock: string; 
    label: string;
    place: number;
    placelabel: string;
    regr: number;
    reglabel: string;
    devise: string 
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is unclear from the error message? You're only including svm, but all of the other properties are required too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. There are some required fields that you don't fill. In the interface, all fields are required :

```js
export interface InternalTransfert {
    svm: number;
    isin: string;
    stock: string; 
    label: string;
    place: number;
    placelabel: string;
    regr: number;
    reglabel: string;
    devise: string 
}
```

So, this is not valid :

```js
this.internalTransfertLines = res.TITRE.map(
                    internalTransfertLine => {
                        return {
                            svm: internalTransfertLine.SVM,
                        }
                    }
                );
```

You fill only the property `svm` and are lacking all the others. Hence, the error message asking you to fill the other fields, `isin`, `stock` etc

You have 2 possibilities :

1. If the fields are not really required, declare them as optional, like this :

```js
export interface InternalTransfert {
    svm?: number;
    isin?: string;
    stock?: string; 
    label?: string;
    place?: number;
    placelabel?: string;
    regr?: number;
    reglabel?: string;
    devise?: string 
}
```

2. If the fields are supposed to be required but you are confortable with not filling them, you can declare `internalTransfertLines` as a `Partial<InternalTransfert>`[] :

```js
internalTransfertLines: Partial<InternalTransfert>[] = [];
```