# Type 'Observable<Student[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Student': id, first_name, last_name, English, and 4 more

Tags: angular, service, crud

I have created two components(table and form) and I want data to be transferred from form to table upon editing. I have written the following code which is throwing the error. Please see to it.console.log(val) is showing the correct value. I want this to be pushed in the data array.I have added both the table component and service

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Student } from '../student';
import { StudentService } from '../student.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {



  data: Student[] = [] 
  single!:Student;
  constructor(public service:StudentService) { }

  getUsers(){
    this.service.getStudents().subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.data=data;
    });
  }

  deleteUsers(id:number){
    this.data = this.service.delete(id,this.data);
  }

  update(id:number){
      this.service.update(id,this.data);
      this.service.currentData.subscribe((val) => {
        console.log(val)
        this.single = val;
        //this.data.push(val)
      });
      this.data.push({
        "English":this.single.English,
        "Hindi":this.single.Hindi,
        "Maths":this.single.Maths,
        "Science":this.single.Science,
        "SST":this.single.SST,
        "first_name":this.single.first_name,
        "last_name":this.single.last_name,
        "id":id
      });
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getUsers();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    if(this.service.getStudents().subscribe()){
        this.service.getStudents().subscribe().unsubscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

Service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from './student';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/throwError';
import { EventEmitter } from 'stream';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentService {


  users: Student[] = [];
  private data1 = new BehaviorSubject(this.getStudents())
  currentData = this.data1.asObservable();


  private url = '../../assets/MOCK_DATA.json'
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { 
 }

   getStudents(): Observable<Student[]> {
    return this.http.get<Student[]>(`${this.url}`);
  }

  delete(id: number, data: Student[]): Student[] {
    data = data.filter(item => item.id !== id)
    return data;
  }

  update(id: number, data: Student[]): Student[] {
    data = data.filter(item => item.id != id)
    this.router.navigate(['/form']);
    return data
  }


  setData(data:any) {
    this.data1.next(data);
   } 
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the missing attributes in your interface. The missing attributes is mentioned in the error/title of your question

Comment: In the interface, I have provided those attributes

Comment: export interface Student {
    id:number;
    first_name:string;
    last_name:string;
    English:number;
    Hindi:number;
    Maths:number;
    Science:number;
    SST:number;
}

Comment: Just curious why you comment `this.data.push(val)` in subscribe function. You should push the data in the subscribe function instead outside of it.

Comment: It was throwing an error

Comment: I have answered a similar question a few days ago. Maybe this will help to understand the problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71659511/is-not-assignable-to-type-internaltransfert/71659731#71659731

Comment: Argument of type 'Observable<Student[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Student'.
  Type 'Observable<Student[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Student': id, first_name, last_name, English, and 4 more.

Comment: Could you please share the code of StudentService ?

Comment: Shared the service file as well

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: this.data.pusg(Val) and this.single=val

Comment: There is a bug here, you are creating a race condition where `this.data.push` runs before `this.single` has been assigned to the new values from the API. Either put `this.data.push` into its own method or inside of the subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I can see, you are trying to push Students[] from StudenService.currentData to another Students[], is it intended or something went wrong?

If you want to add all values from StudentService.currentData then you can try change `this.data.push(val)` to `this.data.push(...val)`

Comment: It gives the following error: Type 'Observable<Student[]>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.

Comment: Hm, is this result of having `this.data.push(...val)`?

Comment: Also why update method looks like delete method?
`update(id: number, data: Student[]): Student[] {
    data = data.filter(item => item.id != id)
    this.router.navigate(['/form']);
    return data
  }`

Comment: On clicking update first I need to delete that and navigate to the new page and then add a new Value

Comment: is navigation a mandatory condition of adding?
Or these are parallel processes?

Comment: Overall my suggestions is following:
1) remove any reassignments from your component, and left only subscription;
2) do not return any data from service methods, or, if it is necessary, leave it as is but instead create modified array using `array.filter` and then call data1.next(array) as you do in `setData`;

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing seems to be due to this line in the service

```
private data1 = new BehaviorSubject(this.getStudents())
```

The type of data1 is `BehaviorSubject<Observable<Student[]>>` because of this line

this causes the type of `currentData` to be `Observable<Observable<Student[]>>` here:

```
currentData = this.data1.asObservable();
```

Then in your component when you do:

```
this.service.currentData.subscribe((val) => {
        console.log(val)
        this.single = val;
        //this.data.push(val)
      });
```

the type of `val` is `Observable<Student[]>`;

Presumably you are getting the error when you do the currently commented line `this.data.push(val)`;

the solution would be to fix the type of the `BehaviorSubject` in the service. Something like this should do:

```
private data1 = new BehaviorSubject<Student[]>([]);
...

getStudents(): Observable<Student[]> {
  return this.http.get<Student[]>(`${this.url}`).pipe(
    tap(data => this.data1.next(data))
  );
}
```

in addition to the above, there is a second issue as pointed by Hephaestus901.

When you do `this.data.push(val)` you are adding an array as an item of the student array in `this.data`. something like: `[st1, st2, [st3, st4]]`.

instead do `this.data = this.data.concat(val)` or as per Hephaestus901's answer

Comment: it gives the error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Student[]'.

Comment: fixed... the behavior subject needed a value. [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lmne5v) for you to play with

Comment: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'Observable<Student[]>'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type 'Observable<Student[]>'.

Comment: It gives the above error